# TINYMCE toolbar to adjust paragraph spacing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I understand that paragraph spacing can be set by css style:

```
tinymce.init({
  /* ... */
  content_style: "body { margin: 0; }",
});
```

Is there any toolbar or anything for adjusting the spacing of the any selected paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

No, TinyMCE has no ready-made features for setting paragraph spacing, but there are a number of ways you can create this feature yourself. A good start is [this demo repository](https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-demos/index.html) documenting a lot of common concepts and best practices.